# circular navigation bootstrap with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   7. How It Works Section
========================================================================== */
.how-it-works {
    background: #f5f5fa;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.board{
 /*width: 75%;
 margin: 60px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px #ccc,-10px 20px #ddd;*/
}
.board .nav-tabs {
 position: relative;
 /* border-bottom: 0; */
 /* width: 80%; */
 margin: 40px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;

}

.board > div.board-inner > .nav-tabs {
 border: none;
}

p.narrow{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

.liner{
 height: 2px;
 background: #ddd;
 position: absolute;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color: #555555;
 cursor: default;
 /* background-color: #ffffff; */
 border: 0;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 outline: 0;
}

span.round-tabs{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
}

span.round-tabs.one{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

li.active span.round-tabs.one, li.active span.round-tabs.two, li.active span.round-tabs.three, li.active span.round-tabs.four, li.active span.round-tabs.five {
 background: #0072c6 !important;
 border: 2px solid #0072c6;
 color: #fff;
}

span.round-tabs.two{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.three{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.four{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.five{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a span.round-tabs{
 background: #fafafa;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
 width: 20%;
}

.nav-tabs > li a{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 border-radius: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li a:hover{
 background: transparent;
}

.tab-content{
}
.tab-pane{
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50px;
}

.btn-outline-rounded{
 padding: 10px 40px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.btn.green{
 background-color:#69cb95;
 /*border: 2px solid #5cb85c;*/
 color: #ffffff;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ){

 .board {
  width: 90%;
  height:auto !important;
 }
 span.round-tabs {
  font-size:16px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
 .tab-content .head{
  font-size:20px;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
 }

 li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
 }

 .btn-outline-rounded {
  padding:12px 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 board">
    <!-- <h2>Welcome to IGHALO!<sup>™</sup></h2>-->
    <div class="board-inner">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <div class="liner"></div>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="home" id="DivPatientDetails" name="PatientDetails" >
                    <span class="round-tabs one">
                        <i class="icon icon-profile-male"></i>01
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-controls="profile" id="DivPatientEligibility" name="PatientEligibility" class="disabled">
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                        <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>02
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-controls="prototyping" id="DivPatientDeclaration" name="PatientDeclaration" class="disabled">
                    <span class="round-tabs three">
                        <i class="icon icon-layers"></i>03
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create circular navigation bar with the help of bootstrap. I have created circular menus but not sure how to show label under those menus. So that it will give some information about those menus.

I have attached css file and screenshots

its creating a page like this - 
[image]

But i want to some labels under those menus and make then active like this -

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using any tag ex: `h4` tag within `span` tag, you can get your answer with active color.

You can also check from [codepen](https://codepen.io/rishirocks/pen/veBXpP)

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   7. How It Works Section
========================================================================== */
.how-it-works {
    background: #f5f5fa;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.board{
 /*width: 75%;
 margin: 60px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px #ccc,-10px 20px #ddd;*/
}
.board .nav-tabs {
 position: relative;
 /* border-bottom: 0; */
 /* width: 80%; */
 margin: 40px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;

}

.board > div.board-inner > .nav-tabs {
 border: none;
}

p.narrow{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

.liner{
 height: 2px;
 background: #ddd;
 position: absolute;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color: #555555;
 cursor: default;
 /* background-color: #ffffff; */
 border: 0;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 outline: 0;
}

span.round-tabs{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
}

span.round-tabs.one{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

li.active span.round-tabs.one, li.active span.round-tabs.two, li.active span.round-tabs.three, li.active span.round-tabs.four, li.active span.round-tabs.five {
 background: #0072c6 !important;
 border: 2px solid #0072c6;
 color: #fff;
}
li.active span.round-tabs.one h4, li.active span.round-tabs.two h4, li.active span.round-tabs.three h4, li.active span.round-tabs.four h4, li.active span.round-tabs.five h4{
 color: #0072c6;
}
span.round-tabs.two{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.three{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.four{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

span.round-tabs.five{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a span.round-tabs{
 background: #fafafa;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
 width: 20%;
}

.nav-tabs > li a{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 border-radius: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {border-color: transparent !important;}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {background-color: transparent;}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {text-decoration: none; background-color: transparent !important;}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {background-color: transparent !important;}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {border:none !important;}
.nav-tabs > li a:hover{
 background: transparent !important;
}
.tab-content{
}
.tab-pane{
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50px;
}

.btn-outline-rounded{
 padding: 10px 40px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.btn.green{
 background-color:#69cb95;
 /*border: 2px solid #5cb85c;*/
 color: #ffffff;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ){

 .board {
  width: 90%;
  height:auto !important;
 }
 span.round-tabs {
  font-size:16px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
 .tab-content .head{
  font-size:20px;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
 }

 li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
 }

 .btn-outline-rounded {
  padding:12px 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 board">
    <!-- <h2>Welcome to IGHALO!<sup>™</sup></h2>-->
    <div class="board-inner">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <div class="liner"></div>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="home" id="DivPatientDetails" name="PatientDetails" >
                    <span class="round-tabs one">
                        <i class="icon icon-profile-male"></i>01
                        <h4>Patient's Details</h4>
                    </span>
                  
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-controls="profile" id="DivPatientEligibility" name="PatientEligibility" class="disabled">
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                        <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>02
                        <h4>Patient's Eligibility</h4>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-controls="prototyping" id="DivPatientDeclaration" name="PatientDeclaration" class="disabled">
                    <span class="round-tabs three">
                        <i class="icon icon-layers"></i>03
                        <h4>Patient's Declaration</h4>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```